# Unable to access SimpleHTTPServer with ip

Tags: network

I created a python http server with

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5555
```

I can access it using `http://localhost:5555` but not using `http://my-macbook-ip:5555` from a different machine.

I'm on Mavericks and firewall is turned off.

What might be blocking incoming connections to this port? Is there any way to tell my mac to accept http connections on this port?

Comment: Can you access via the ip from the serving machine can you ping the other machine and what is the exact error you get (I have the same setup as you and it just works)

Comment: Cannot access via the ip from the serving machine either. Browser is spinning with "Sending request…". But I can ping my macbook.

Comment: What happens when you telnet on that port ?

Comment: My mistake. Can't ping my macbook.